# Using a tab control, is it possible to dynamically load multiple tabs at runtime while maintaining state of each tab?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

The functionality I'm looking for is similar to a web browser with tabs.

The main site navigation would consist of typical links. When a link is clicked, a tab is dynamically loaded with that pages content. The user can add multiple tabs by clicking navigation links.

If they begin filling out a form on one tab, then switch tabs and come back, the form data should still be there.

The tab controls I've looked at (DevExpress, AJAX tab control) don't allow this, or don't maintain tab data when switching from tab to tab. The tab control is regenerated with every post back.

Maybe I am over thinking this and there is a simple solution.  Any ideas? I can use DevExpress controls, jquery, or regular asp.net controls.
Thanks!
Kevin

Comment: why don't you go for the jquery UI tabs

Comment: I just attempted jquery ui tabs.  Form data is not maintained between tabs.  If I enter data, switch tabs then switch back, the form data is gone.

Comment: @Kevin are you telling the jQuery UI tabs to cache? If not then its refetching from the web server every time.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify.  The regular jquery tabs use divs on the same page as the tab control.  I am looking to pull a page off the server and use that as the tab content.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?